# Getting records for the previous calendar month

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I am trying to get the records of the previous month. That is say we are in February - I'd want to get records from 1st January to 31st January.

I tried:

```
$approved_reviews_lastMonth = ReviewHeader::where('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(1))->count();
```

But this does not get any for the last month.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format()` to get the `Year-Month` format, and use `like` to get the previous month count.

```php
$approved_reviews_lastMonth = ReviewHeader::where('created_at', 'like', Carbon::now()->subMonth(1)->format("Y-m")."%")->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween` as well.

```
$firstDayofPreviousMonth = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth()->toDateString();
$lastDayofPreviousMonth = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->toDateString();
$approved_reviews_lastMonth = ReviewHeader::whereBetween('created_at', [$firstDayofPreviousMonth,$lastDayofPreviousMonth])->count();
```